# Branch io change subdomain

Tags: ios, iphone, branch, deep-linking, branch.io

I have a functional product of iOS App, with the domain that branch.io give me, and works very well.

Name is for example: t55s.app.link   But the client said me that is possible to change t55s for other characters,

for example: demo.app.link   If possible?, When put “demo.app.link” in the app custom domain, is ok but the link https://demo.app.link.abc/XXX link said me “file not found”.

How to put custom domain?

Answer (score 1):

Alex from Branch.io: absolutely. Take a look at the [documentation page for changing subdomains](https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/link-domain-subdomain/guide/#changing-your-applink-subdomain)